# Move WordPress site from Yahoo Small Business

Tags: wordpress, yahoo-api, filezilla

I am trying to move a site from Yahoo Small Business to a local hosting company.  I am able to log in to the host with FileZilla.

I have also downloaded the files from YSB and have them locally.  But the local hosting company gave me a test host and I cannot access cPanel to upload the files.  Also, when I try to put the url.com/cpanel I get directed to the home page of the current site still listed with Yahoo.  I have imported the files from my computer to the new host via Filezilla, but I'm not seeing anything and can't log in.

I am unable to change the DNS of Yahoo to the test host.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you changed the database data in wp-config? have you exported the database from YSB and importet it by the new host? changed the url in wp_options table? any rules in .htaccess? maybe some cache data?

Comment: If you're having trouble access cPanel, your best bet is to contact the new host for support.

Comment: first thing you will have to do is DNS change. And if you want to test wordpress site with any other domain, you can test it using IP address in new server.
and to transfer website, Duplicator plugin will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @yohoprashant  that you will need to do a few work arounds until you migrate your DNS.  Most hostign companies will give you a temporary URL (IP address) and which should give you access to cPanel and testing your initiatl WordPress install.  111.111.111.111/cpanel

Wordpress has a great step by step that you should be able to follow once you get the basic WorkdPress install either through the download or cPanel install.  Check it out here:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.  The company in qeustion did not provide me with an IP address, but instead gave me state4.companyname.net.  I think the problem is I just don't have enough knowledge to complete the task.  The company is going to migrate the site for me.  Thanks everyone for your help/resources!